# Using EntityFramework_SimplifyLimitOperations in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.5.2

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720772(v=vs.110).aspx says that since .NET 4.5.2 we can use a setting EntityFramework_SimplifyLimitOperations to simplify some Entity Framework queries. There is pretty much no documentation on that setting elsewhere. My question is how safe it is to use this setting without prior investigation. My assumption is that it can not harm, just improve some queries generated by EF. But can there be any hidden aspects?

Additionally, what versions of EF do support it?

Comment: Profile Your Queries with the setting on and off

Comment: @ErikEJ, surely I can profile, but this is time consuming. My question is whether I can safely switch it on, hoping that it can have no harm whatsoever and may cause performance improvement.